# Kronecker pairing on finite cohomology group and homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Assume $M$ is a smooth connected manifold with $H^k(M)$ finite, $k\leq \dim M$. Is it true that the Kronecker pairing
$$
\langle,\rangle:H^k(M)\times H_k(M)\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}
$$
$$
\langle[\varphi],[\Sigma]\rangle=\varphi(\Sigma)
$$
is trivial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** : a morphism $\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ is always zero.